# Flurry integration in phone-gap project causing issues

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am integrating flurry with the help of
https://github.com/jfpsf/flurry-phonegap-plugin

I manually copied the FlurryAnalytics-6.0.0.jar file
[image]

I have installed following plugins 
[image]

but when I run the command for creating build

```
cordova run
```

It gives me following errors

```
    $ cordova run
Running command: /Users/rauf/Documents/Chatbudi/Chatbudi-client/platforms/android/cordova/run 
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device '192.168.56.101:5555'.
Running: /Users/rauf/Documents/Chatbudi/Chatbudi-client/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/rauf/Documents/Chatbudi/Chatbudi-client/platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=x86 -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
         file:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
         file:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.aar
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.232 secs

/Users/rauf/Documents/Chatbudi/Chatbudi-client/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/rauf/Documents/Chatbudi/Chatbudi-client/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/rauf/Documents/Chatbudi/Chatbudi-client/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=x86,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/rauf/Documents/Chatbudi/Chatbudi-client/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Please let me know what I have to do for it, build works fine before flurry plugin integration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the lead maintainer of this plugin. We have a patch that should fix this problem, and it will be integrated in the next day or two. You should really address questions about this project to https://github.com/jfpsf/flurry-phonegap-plugin

Comment: please let me know when you fix it, I waiting~~~

Comment: This doesn't seem very active. Are there any alternates available. I am trying to decide which to use for analytics in my phone gap app - Google, Flurry or MixPanel ?

Comment: @John Potter  : Did it fixed ? I am still facing issue